# Implement the function returnthree()

Tags: python-3.4

Hi I am trying to Implement the function returnThree() in python that takes a string as a parameter and returns the first three characters of the string. If the string has length less than 3, then an empty string should be returned.

This is what I have so far:

def returnThree(s):

```
return (s[:3])
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
def return_three(s):
if len(s) < 3:
    return ''
else:
    return s[:3]
```

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck! Python is great fun!

Comment: Thank you once more. Also, I have one last problem that I can not figure out. would you be able to help me out with this last one please? if you are this is the link to the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866616/function-printgreater I really appreciate your help.