# Function printGreater()

Tags: python-3.4

I am trying to implement a function `printGreater()` that takes a list of numbers and a numeric value as parameter. It prints the numbers in the list that are greater than the value, all on one line with a space between them. If an empty list is provided as the first parameter, the function doesn't print anything.

This is what I have so far:

```
def printGreater(nums, value):

lstN = (int[nums],value)
if nums > value:
    print(nums, end=", ")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def printGreater(nums, value):
    #First create an empty list to hold onto all the numbers larger than value
    greater = [];

    #Loop overall the input values, saving all large ones
    for num in nums:            
        if num > value:
            #Convert to a string for printing
            greater.append(str(num))

    #Print them out with spaces in between
    print( ' '.join(greater) )

#Then test with this
printGreater([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you'll want to use a for loop. I'll place the code, then explain what's going on.

```
def print_greater(nums_list, value):
    string = ''
    for num in nums_list:
        if num > value:
            string += str(num) + ' '
    return string
```

First, I'm initializing a new string variable:

```
string = ''
```

Next, I start an iteration loop:

```
for num in nums_list:
    ...
```

What that iteration (for) loop is going to do, is to start with the first item in a list a give it, and make that item 'num'. Then I can do whatever I want with that item. Once I'm finished, it will move on to the second item, and so on.

```
        if num > value:
            string += str(num) + ' '
```

In this case, I want to compare num to value. If num is great, I want to add onto the string I initialized earlier. That's what the += means...

```
string += str(num) + ' '
```

is the same as

```
string = string + str(num) + ' '
```

Finally, at the end, I return the string.

Hope that helps!